# Why does passing a struct with const reference members cause a C2280 error?

Tags: c++, struct, reference, constants

I ran into a issue while attempting to assign a `struct` with `const&` members to a map.

```
struct test {
    const int& number;

    test(const int& cnumber) : number(cnumber) {}

    test(const test&) = default;
    test& operator=(const test&) = default;

};
```

```
int main () {

    std::map<std::string, test> testmap;

    testmap["asd"] = test(2);

}
```

Running this code causes the error `C2280 'test &test::operator =(const test &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`

Can anyone explain to me what the issue is here?
This is a minimal reproducible example. In my real project the data is much larger and therefore it would not be wise to pass by value.

Comment: Why do you need a reference to an `int`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is just a minimal reproducible example. In my real project it's much larger then a `int`

Comment: what is default implementation of assignment operator if class contains a reference?

Comment: Um, `test()` default ctor is deleted.  Amusing that your error shows up before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have reference members, the `test` type is not assignable by default. So this line:

```
testmap["asd"] = test(2);  // error
```

won't compile since it needs a user-defined `operator=`, which you have not provided.

Instead, you could do:

```
testmap.emplace("asd",test(2));  // ok
```

Here's a [demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aPfKd5).

Answer (score 5):

References are not assignable.  Because of that, the default `operator =` that the compiler provides is implicitly deleted.  Even though you have

```
test& operator=(const test&) = default;
```

the "default" `operator =` here is a deleted operator so you still don't have one.  You either need to not use a reference, or write your own `operator =` that does what you want.

Comment: Mentioning that if the code did work, it would generate nonsense, might help.  Also, default ctor is deleted.